# Export multiple objects in sysdata.rda with roxygen2

Tags: r, roxygen2

I have two objects (`page.height` and `page.width`) in a `sysdata.rda` file of my package. I have documented them with `roxygen2` like this

```
#'@name page.height
#'@aliases page.width
#'@title Standard dimensions
#'\itemize{
#'  \item{page.height}{Maximal height of a figuur (in inch)}
#'  \item{page.width}{Width of a figure covering two columns (in inch)}
#'}
#'@docType data
#'@export
#'@usage page.height
#'@keywords datasets
NULL
```

The `page.height` object is exported, but the `page.width` object is not. How should I document this so that both are exported and documented on the same helpfile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found it in the Roxygen2 documentation: explicitly name the object to export

```
#'@export page.height page.width
```

Comment: If you're exporting and documenting the data, shouldn't it be external data in the /data folder rather than in sysdata.rda?